# How to run 32-bit CCSC compiler in 64-bit environment?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, chroot

I have a compiler, [CCSC](https://www.ccsinfo.com/content.php?page=compilers), that I haven't been able to run since upgrading to 64 bit Ubuntu. It is supposed to be compatible, but it just core dumps and crashes. So I need to reboot into my 32 bit Ubuntu to use it. CCS isn't supporting it at all.

I'm wondering if I could use chroot in the compiler call path in my IDE and just run the one program in the 32bit environment.

Or if not, any ideas of how I could accomplish this. I'm using XC8 now, but I have to support firmware that was written for CCS.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this case I would likely setup a 32-bit environment in a virtual machine. That is, install 32-bit Ubuntu in Virtual Box as a guest, and then run virtual box when developing. I often do similar. I have a Ubuntu host, and guests like Fedora, OpenBSD, NetBSD, etc. I push a code change, and then pull it in the VM's to ensure nothing breaks.

Comment: Thanks, I totally understand what you're saying. But, it's a lot like booting to the other machine. I need to use the old IDE and tools to do the development, and then switch to my main OS for everything else. Certainly works, but not the optimal solution. Thanks.